# How do I get a value from an associative array using Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I am trying to get "readerSession" from an associative array and put it into a variable. This is what I've tried.

**Code**

```
println(thevalue)
```

**Returned**

```
{
    readerSession = 41;
    tax = 7;
    tax2 = 6;
    taxName = GST;
    taxName2 = PST;
}
```

So readerSession is equal to 41, now lets see if I can get ahold of it.

**Code**

```
println(thevalue["readerSession"])
```

**Returned** Optional(41)

Ok great, exactly what I want, now I'll try to put it into a variable.

**Code**

```
var readerSession = thevalue["readerSession"] as? String ?? "0"
println("READER SESSION \(readerSession) ")
```

**Returned** READER SESSION 0

Why is it "0"??? It should be "41"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you get `"0"` is because the value stored in the associative array is an `Int`, not a `String`. Therefore, when you try casting to `String` the cast returns null, so the right-hand side of the `??` kicks in, and you get a zero string.

You can fix it like this:

```
var readerSession : AnyObject = thevalue["readerSession"] ?? "0"
```

Comment: but this way `readerSession` is sometimes an `NSNumber` and sometimes an `NSString`, which cannot be a good design

Comment: @newacct I agree - this is only a workaround for the given design.